# R: function which check for complete design

Tags: r, function

I want to create a function who takes from 1 to 10 vectors and returns Yes or No meaning that all my vectors represent a "complete design".

Here is an example of what I would call a "complete design":

> a <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)
>
> b <- c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2)
>
> c <- c(1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2)

It is a complete design because:
For all levels of all vectors there are (at the same position) all levels of all other vectors the same number of times.

Here is 2 examples of "incomplete design":
(In the two following examples a and b match but c does not match a neither with b)

example 1:

> a <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)
>
> b <- c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2)
>
> c <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)

example 2:

> a <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)
>
> b <- c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2)
>
> c <- c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2)

Hope I am clear. The whole idea is that I have a data set and this data set is explained by the factors a,b,c,d,e,etc... And I want a function that tell me wether I'm testing a complete or an incomplete design before running an aov() on it.

Thanks a lot !

The question to ask in the function I want to create is something like:
when a equal a given level (let's say 2 for example). We look at b[which(a==2)] and check whether all levels of b are contained in b[which(a==2)] and also check if all levels of b[which(a==2)] are repeated the same number of times.

Comment: sorry, but how is `levels(factor(a)) == c(1,2,3)` in all of `a, b, and c`? And what do you mean by `a` and `b` match, but not `c` with either `a` or `b`? What's matching?

Comment: of course all vectors (a,b,c in my examples) do not have the same number of levels. I just wrote an example of levels of one vector. But I deleted it now.
When I say a and b match I mean that if you delete the vector c a and b make a complete design. Meaning that only for c the number of levels of other vectors are not equal for each level of c.
In the example 1 of incomplete design:
c have 3 levels which are 1,2 and 3. for the level 5 of c there are only the levels 2 and 3 of the vector. As it is missing a 1 in the vector a in a position number where is a 5 in the vector c.

Comment: Is it now a bit more understandable ?!

Comment: not really. I have no idea what you mean by: `number of levels of other vectors are not equal for each level of c`. What is `level 5` of `c` in example 1??

Comment: You may want to take a look at package [AlgDesign](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/AlgDesign/index.html). It contains functions to generate and evaluate experimental designs.

Comment: I think you're confusing between `levels` and `values`.

Comment: I'd describe that design as completely crossed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you might be able to use `interaction` in some way as a first-cut in deciding whether your data are complete.

Looking at your examples, it seems like there should always be one unique combination (not 2, not 0) of all the unique levels within each vector. So, for the first set you show:

```
> all(table(interaction(a, b, c)) == 1)
[1] TRUE
```

And, for the other two examples, if you did the same, you would get `FALSE` as the result.

---

Another option would be to assume that we can treat variable `a` as a grouping variable, and put all the vectors into a `data.frame` like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(a = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),
                  b = c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2),
                  c = c(1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2))
```

Once we have done that, we can `split` that `data.frame` as follows:

```
DF1 <- split(df1[-1], df1[1])
```

Then, we can write a little function to check to see that each part of the split is equal. We'll cheat a little bit and use `merge`, but there must be more robust ways to do this. The idea is that if we use `merge` on inputs that are identical, it should just end up a single `data.frame` that is the same as all the input `data.frame`s.

Here's a (not so robust--not extensively tested) function that can be used as a starting point.

```
myFun <- function(myList) {
  all.equal(Reduce(function(x, y) 
    merge(x, y, all = TRUE, sort = FALSE), myList),
            myList[[1]], check.attributes = FALSE)
}
```

Applied to `DF1`, it gives us `TRUE`, but try the following:

```
df2 <- data.frame(a = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),
                  b = c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2),
                  c = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3))
df3 <- data.frame(a = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),
                  b = c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2),
                  c = c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2))

DF1 <- split(df1[-1], df1[1])
DF2 <- split(df2[-1], df2[1])
DF3 <- split(df3[-1], df3[1])

myFun(DF1)
# [1] TRUE
myFun(DF2)
# [1] "Component 1: Numeric: lengths (6, 4) differ" "Component 2: Numeric: lengths (6, 4) differ"
myFun(DF3)
# [1] "Component 1: Numeric: lengths (10, 4) differ" "Component 2: Numeric: lengths (10, 4) differ"
```

Answer (score 4):

There's a very simple way to do this using plyr's `id()` function:

```
library(plyr)
a <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)
b <- c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2)
c <- c(1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2)

ids <- id(data.frame(a, b, c))
attr(ids, "n") == length(unique(ids))
# [1] TRUE

d <- c(1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,3)
ids <- id(data.frame(a, b, d))
attr(ids, "n") == length(unique(ids))
# [1] FALSE
```

`id()` works by assigning a unique id to each row in the input, in such a way that there's room for all possible combinations. The output contains an attribute, `n`, which gives the total possible number of combinations.

Comment: +1. Did not know about the `id()` function in plyr until now.